# how does django-allauth generate the username?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm using django-allauth and have enabled auto signup but I'm not sure how id decides on the username to use.

for example I just tested the auto signup with my Facebook account

my Facebook username is **davidgriver**

my Facebook first and last name are **David Griver**

django-allauth signed me up automatically under the username **ddd**

can someone explain to me why that happened and how I can make it either take the Facebook username or if that's not possible take the first and last name make them lowercase and remove the space

the google one is a bit smarter, it just takes the first name, but that's pretty bad because first names are common and not unique at all.

Ideally with google I would like to just take whatever is before the @ symbol and use that.

Comment: Which version of allauth you use? It should take your fb account name https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/providers/facebook/provider.py#L170

Comment: django-allauth (0.22.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`allauth` generates unique usernames by using `generate_unique_username` method defined in utils.py. Here is the [link](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/utils.py#L97)